# Changing `auto_increment_increment` in a DB at a web hosting provider

Tags: mysql, cloudbees

I deployed a web application to CloudBees, and created a MySQL DB with the one-click GUI. It looks like `auto_increment_increment` option is set to 10 (`id` in a table increases by 10 with each new row). I tried to change the `auto_increment_increment`:

```
SET GLOBAL auto_increment_increment=1;
```

But I got an error: `Error Code: 1227. Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation`.

How can I change the `auto_increment_increment`?

Comment: Are you sure? is a very extrange configuration... if you execute: `SHOW variables LIKE '%auto_increment%';` what values gives you?.

Comment: The error looks access rights permission. can you try this, If u get possible als? truncate the table and again run this query? Because already you have set 10 and inserted a table.

Comment: @Sal00m I get `auto_increment_increment` = 10, and three more variables.

Comment: @punitha I recreated the table. The issue is still there.

Comment: just try it SET IDENTITY_INSERT table_name OFF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extrange configuration in your provider....

According to the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-statement.html):

> The SUPER privilege is required to set global variables.

So you need to access with a user with this privilege, you should ask to your provider about it.

Of course you can change this variable for your session:

```
SET SESSION auto_increment_increment=1;
```

You don't need any especial privilege to do this